# Why can a "const int*" point to a non-const int?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

following code in the picture is a example to illustrate  pointer to a constant integer. My question:

1. Since int w is not declare as a constant integer, why it says that the pointer is pointing to a constant integer?
2. why we cannot try the last line?

If the pointer to a constant should not be assigned to any other value after assigning to the first value, so what makes the difference between a pointer to a constant and a constant pointer then? ( For my understanding, a constant pointer cannot be changed, but a pointer to constant can be changed...

[image]

Comment: "It changes the thing in the pointer, not the constant value itself..." is not correct. The previously line (`p = &w`) assigned a new value to the pointer while the last line (`*p = 3`) goes and mucks with the object pointed to.

Comment: What on earth is this mess you're pasting into your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C allows a "pointer to `const int`" to actually point to a non-const `int`, as you found out. It doesn't cause any problems, so why not allow it?

The pointer doesn't remember whether it's pointing to a `const int` or to a normal `int`, so you always have to treat it as if it's pointing to a `const int`. That means `*p = 3;` isn't allowed, because the compiler doesn't know for sure* that `*p` isn't a `const int`.

* Modern compilers might well be able to figure this out, but the language says they have to pretend they can't, and they won't *always* be able to anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Think of `const` as a restriction - it prevents you from writing. Then the meaning is clear: `const int *` *adds* a restriction that may not exist on the base variable.

C lets you add this kind of restriction freely. The thing you can't do is to remove restrictions - you can't make a `int *` point at a `const int` without casting.

Comment: According to what you say, the pointer to a constant should not be assigned to any other value after assigning to the first value. So what makes the difference between a pointer to a constant and a constant pointer then? ( For my understanding, a constant pointer cannot be changed, but a pointer to constant can be changed...

Comment: a pointer to constant can be changed (i.e. it points to other variables) but not the value it points to